# is it possible to have content break to next line with flex when content reaches edge inside of FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am new in react-native and I was trying to create one component and try to pass props on that by using FlatList . But, FlatList show either on Vertical or Horizontal View, i need View in next line when View reaches edges. 
But i can't found any solution.

```
        data={data}
        //Optional
        // horizontal={true}
        // numColumns={4}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TrendingTopicsDesign image={item.imageuri} title={item.title} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

I expect My view came out with break when it reaches edge

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `display:flex` then [`flex-wrap: wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) on the parent element which will force the child element to the next line

Comment: I have tried :
<FlatList 

  style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', }}
 data={data}
 renderItem= { }
/>

But still doesn't work for me on react-native.
How should i do ? and How do i implement jsx ?
#Thanks_in_advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS property of `flex-wrap: wrap;` along with the `display: flex;` property for making child items to appear on the next line when they reach the edge of the screen.